# Python Interpreter within Interpreter

Tags: python, subprocess, interpreter

So I was learning about the Python `subprocess` module. Withing the interpreter, I typed `subprocess.call("python")` and another interpreter opened within the existing interpreter, and things got pretty weird. While typing, I noticed some characters weren't being echoed properly and I had to type them repeatedly. Plus, plain Enters (or returns) were adding lot more than just chevrons on the screen. Here's part of the output:

[image: Interpreter within Interpreter]

Can someone explain what was happening? I know the question may be too broad or vague, but I'm unable to be specific here.

Comment: @HFBrowning `exit` or `quit`, I'm sure.

Comment: @HFBrowning I was trying quit() and just pressing return repeatedly.

Comment: Hm, just tried it myself with no problem. Maybe someone with a similar set up to you (I'm on Windows) has an idea.

Comment: @HFBrowning Yeah. I was using the Mac Terminal. I saw that the problem doesn't occur with IDLE shell.

Comment: Well, you have opened another interpreter in the current one, but the current one **already** fetches the input, therefore to "pass" the input further you'll need to do it each second time. For example after `Popen` the object is created, then `<enter>`, and *then* the new interpreter prints to the current one. If you then type right after the interpreter is opened e.g. `help()`, it'll be interpreted in the first one, while now the second one waits for your input. If now you give it `<enter>`, the second interpreter just "passes" and the `help()` output continues...

Comment: ... Windows, 3.5.2, can't explain it better. Basically it fights for input and output because you're doing something stupid. If you *need* to use it, just interpret a **file** and definitely not in an already opened interpreter, but also in a separate file - `python main.py`, where in main.py you call that subprocess and the string is also something like `python second_main.py`. Maybe it'd be better to explain it with two `input()` functions waiting for each other?

Comment: @KeyWeeUsr Thanks! Yeah, I used to call other scripts that way, but this time I just wondered what would happen if I just call python.

Comment: @SamChats check the answer it should hopefully clean some things :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll try to make it straightforward to reproduce, so that you can see the collision.

1. `python`
2. `import os; os.getpid();` # we'll need this, get it to clipboard or something

   > `296236` # for me
3. `import subprocess`
4. `subprocess.Popen('python')`

> `<subprocess.Popen object at somewhere_over_the_rainbow>` # object is created, python probably waits for a chance to push it to the console as a command "python"
>
> `>>>`

5. `<import&get pid>`

> `296236` # the command is pushed, the new process spawned

You spawned another Python process into a current open console that **already** waits for an input. The "child" process now exists but still can't demand to get an input, because the main one is still "on the turn". Imagine it like a queue. The output for `import os;os.getpid()` now will still be the main process' PID and *now* the child one gets its turn.

6. `<import&get pid>`

> `296236`
>
> `>>> Python 3.5.2 (v3.5.2:4def2a2901a5, Jun 25 2016, 22:01:18) [MSC v.1900 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
>   Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.` # from second process, it did its stuff in its turn, now main process wants to talk

7. `<import&get pid>`  # in main process

> `296236`

8. `<import&get pid>`  # in second process

> `296800`

9. `<import&get pid>`  # in main process

> `296236`

10. `<import&get pid>`  #in second process

> `296800`

...and alternating again and again. The fun begins when you want to `exit()`, because the fight for input is still ongoing:

11. `import os;os.getpid();exit()`  #in second process

> `296800`
>
> and a clean empty line

12. `import os;os.getpid();exit()`  #in main process

> `296236`
>
> `C:\some folder>`

Basically it fights for an IO operation in a queue because you're doing something stupid. If you need to use it, just interpret a file and definitely not in an already opened interpreter, but also in a separate file. For example:

**main.py**

```
import subprocess
subprocess.Popen('python other.py')
```

**other.py**

```
print('hello')
exit()
```

**console**

```
python main.py
```